# In my app, how to use the same dependencies used in my library (aar)

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

I have an Android Library that I export in a local Maven.
To compile this lib, I need roboguice:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
    ....
}
```

To compile my app, I need my lib, but also roboguice:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile 'my.lib:1.0'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
    ....
}
```

Is there a way to load all the symbols from the dependencies in the library, such that I don't have to include them again in the app?
My example only shows roboguice, but I need to do the same for junit, jackson, robolectric etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't need to be a way. Your lib's dependencies will be resolved automatically. i.e. In your main app, just:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'my.lib:1.0'
}
```

Then your lib's dependencies (roboguice...) will also be compiled.

Comment: Not working, that's why I opened the question on SO.